# Docker Copy failed no source files were specified

Tags: docker, maven, dockerfile

I am trying to copy a jar file in my dockerfile. whne I run build, I can see the jar under target/dockerbuild. But docker does not see the file and I am getting following error.

```
 COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

My docker file has those lines for copy operation:

```
ENV MY_HOME=/usr/local/myhome
COPY target/dockerbuild/my.jar $MY_HOME
```

Why it cannot find the jar although it exists under the target.

Comment: What's the exact `docker build` command you're running?  Where is the Dockerfile in your source tree:

Answer (score 2):

Your error looks like it could be one of the following:

- The file doesn't exist in the specified path
- The path doesn't exist (relative to the build context - if you use 'docker build .' then the specified path must exist relative to the current directory)

Please can you share what you run to build your docker image (so we can see the build context) and also your directory structure

Answer (score 1):

Verify that in your .dockerignore do not have that path (target) in your exceptions

Comment: i do not have .dockerignore file.

Comment: Can you paste your dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

That error said  file `target/dockerbuild/my.jar` is not exist. The architecture of COPY in Dockerfile is:

```
COPY {file in your host} {path of target in docker image}
```

Comment: I could not understand what you meant. what I meant was jar file exist in my host, but copy command does not find/see it.

Comment: your file is jar? for example  you can not use tar file with copy in dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar situation.

```
ls target/dockerbuild/my.jar
```

proofed that the file exists but docker build claimed that no source files were specified. However there also was a tiny hint that I did not notice for some time:

When using COPY with more than one source file, the destination must be a directory and end with a /

Though I only had one file I added the / to the copy destination and the build succeeded.